# How to concencate two tab separated data frames for each unique subfolder

Tags: python, pandas

I'm facing a puzzling thing.

```
C:// Total / a12 / a12.tsv
C:// Total / a12 / a12_1.tsv

C:// Total /b12 / b12.tsv
C:// Total /b12 / b12_1.tsv
```

As you can tell, I have a directory 'Total' and sub-directories 'a12' and 'b12' respectively. In each of the sub-directories, I have exactly two .tsv files. My aim is to load each one successfully into two pandas data frame and concencate the data frame into one, and output the output as a file:

```
C: // Total / a12 / a12_combined.tsv
C: // Total / b12 / b12_combined.tsv
```

I'd like to combine a12.tsv and a12_1.tsv into a12_combined.tsv in the folder a12 and same with b12_combined.tsv in b12

In reality, I have twenty-six different sub-folders to iterate through. I tried using glob.glob to scan each recursively, but it ended up creating a master folder combining all of the four dataframes into one.

This is all I have so far:

```
import glob as glob
import pandas as pd
file = glob.glob('Total/**/*.tsv')

    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines=(False), sep = '\t') for f in file])

    print(file)

    df.to_csv ("merged.tsv" , sep = '\t')
```

I'd also like to name the output of each file as ".tsv file name _ combined" if that makes sense. If there is another question similar to this, I'd appreciate a linkage.

Comment: Iterate the top-level folder and accumulate data frames in a list and finally use concatenate. @Yo Mama

Answer (score 0):

you have to access folder first  then  files like

```
folders = glob('Total/*') # get all floders in Total

for i in folders:
    files = glob(f'{i}/*.tsv') #this will give files of a folder
    print(files)
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines=(False), sep = '\t') for f in file])
    df.to_csv (f"{i}/merged.tsv" , sep = '\t') #save in that sub folder
```